# Credentials do not work for "docker login"

Tags: docker, authentication, credentials, unauthorized

Copy/pasting my username and password into the Docker Hub website works fine.

The password is long, but does not contain shell-breaking symbols.

Copy/pasting those same credentials into command-line `docker login` results in an `incorrect username or password` error. I have tried passing the credentials interactively (both copy/pasting and typing) and through command line args, same result:

```
# INTERACTIVE
$ docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: my@email.com
Password: <REDACTED>
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

# COMMAND LINE
$ docker login -u my@email.com -p <REDACTED>
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

Comment: I think your username is not the same as your email.

Comment: @mustaccio It is, and I've tried the "Docker ID" as well, still doesn't work.

Comment: May be the `docker` version mismatch then?

Comment: @mustaccio Just installed this morning: `Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

@mustaccio was correct.

The Docker Hub website allows you to login with either your username OR your email, and the website does not require a case-correct username.

`docker login` *DOES* require a case-correct username, and *DOES NOT* work with your email address.

When I signed up I chose a camel-cased username e.g.:

```
MyUsername
```

Docker forces this username to all lower case in practice. When you log in, you'll see your correct username in the upper right-hand corner of the website. In this example:

```
myusername
```

The website allows you to login with **MyUsername** or **myusername**.

`docker login` only allows **myusername**.

Comment: Even though it was mentioned in the comments above, could you please also emphasize the fact that `docker login` does not work at all with email, giving the same error ? This is what happened to me, and your answer led me the right way :)

Comment: @AdelaN Done! Thank you!

Comment: For me, the password was the problem. On the website it worked without any issues, but trying to login from the command line gave me the same error. That was because I had a strong password with all kinds of characters... changing to a simple password worked for me.

Comment: I, too had special characters, and was running into the problem.  I wonder WHICH characters are not allowed...  !@#$%^&*() ?  wish I knew

Comment: Well, in my case it looks like the password special character "exclamation mark" symbol was the cause of my particular problem - using Portus to authenticate against Active Directory/LDAP, the command line: docker login {my.portus.server} was not working, but logging into the GUI of the portus server was fine...

Comment: Only lowercase for the username was the solution.

Answer (score 13):

Same issue happens if you didn't logout and if you have put EMAIL address for login.

```
docker logout
docker login
```

DONOT PUT EMAIL ADDRESS, instead ENTER USERNAME

Comment: This is the right answer! If you login at hub.docker.com you'll see your username in the top right-hand corner.

Answer (score 6):

I used a password generator that put special characters in my password, I was able to login in my browser but not through the cli.  I changed it to just letters and numbers and it worked.

Comment: Yes, just use password with alphanumeric characters and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`
2. `sudo docker login`

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by this way.
Go to https://hub.docker.com/settings/security and create a new token in my account.

To login use
`docker login` command
And type:

`myusername in lowercase` and

`token (instead of password)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that helped specially that I didn't want to change my password to only letters and numbers

Comment: tried, did not help!

Answer (score 2):

If You are using git bash on Windows then use following command:

```
 winpty docker login --username <yourusername>
```

It will prompt for password. Enter your password. Message "Login Succeeded" displayed.

"yourusername" you can get on right top corner when logged in docker official site. 
With your email it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Adding special characters like @ in password may mess-up login to docker from terminal , even if we use correct case and everything else correct . But it will work from website if we use a special char in password.

So basically use letters and number only in password , don't use special char for docker login

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still experiencing this after ensuring your user and pass is correct, generate a token at account settings>security>new access token , I was struggling for an hour but using a token worked. Don't know why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone making my mistake: Run sudo docker login -u USERNAME. When it asks for the password, if you're running sudo for the first time on Terminal, the first password it asks for sudo. Enter your sudo password. Then, it will ask for a password the second time, and this is where you enter your Docker password.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:
Right click docker on the system tray and sign out. Then sign in but use your docker hub username not email address.

Answer (score 0):

For logging into hub.docker.com, what worked for me was make sure you DO NOT specify 'hub.docker.com'!!!  Different versions of API-DNS?   All of this after I spent a good hour changing my password, changing my token, etc.

Just simply:

```
docker login --username=myusername <enter>
theToken <enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. docker login
2. Do not use email id. Use your username in **smallcase** and then give password.
3. You should be successfully login.

Answer (score 0):

please login with your DOCKER ID and password

this would work instantly

Answer (score 0):

If, just like me, anyone reading these answers attempted login before and it failed, your *pass* password store may already have a key, which causes some kind of unhandled exception for Docker CLI. If, also like me, the stored key is useless, you can delete it with the instructions below.

```
$ pass #this will list your keys tree
$ pass rm -r KEY_OR_KEY_DIRECTORY #if your key is inside a node in the tree, then it's a directory and you must specify -r parameter for recursive deletion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issue:

---

ERROR: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper/manifests/7.1.0": unauthorized: incorrect username or password

---

Then login to the docker using this:

$ docker login -u  < userName >

Enter your password